# ASP.NET Core : how to sum the column based on another tables's column

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core.

```
public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }

public double Total => this.LineItems.Sum(x => x.LineTotal);
```

LineItem

```
public int Quantity { get; set; }
public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
public double LineTotal => Math.Round(this.Quantity * this.UnitPrice, 2);
```

The error said `Sum()` is not used properly.

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Answer (score 1):

I think this error may be due to Object reference not set to an instance of an object,you could try to modify the code:

```
public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<LineItem> LineItems =new List<LineItem>（）；
```

And I get the  excepted result  after I changed the codes,If you have any other problems please tell me more details.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai7uB.gif)